# Uploading LFS Objects stuck at 0 when pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

whenever I go to push to my repository with LFS, it gets stuck at 0 and does not push. Any idea on what the problem is? Thanks

[picture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofGU4.jpg)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text; they are not searchable and not accessible.  You should run the command with `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and see why it's failing.  If you post the output here (only as a code block), redact the `Authorization` headers first.